# asp.net core showing correct url on address bar

Tags: asp.net-core, url, parameters, controller

This is my code for controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyView_001(long id = null)
{
  if(id != null)
     {
          ViewData["DataValue"] = id;
          return View("MyView_002");
     }
   return View();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> MyView_002()
{
   return View();
}
```

As you can see, I have two view (MyView_001,MyView_002) , first I will call the `MyView_001?id=1` , if the `id` is not null , I want to return `MyView_002`.  It's so far ok for this , but the issue is the url show on address bar.  It's showing like `MyView_001?id=1` even `MyView_002` is showing currently.
I want to show only `MyView_002` in my url.
How can I solve it ?

**Update**
And I also want to use `ViewData["DataValue"]` in `MyView_002`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly return View, you can use `RedirectToAction`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyView_001(long id)
{
    if(id != 0)
    {
        TempData["DataValue"] = id.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("MyView_002");
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Update:**

Use session for persistence：

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyView_001(long id = 0)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", id.ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("MyView_002");
        }
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MyView_002()
    {
        var id = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Id"));
        return View(id);
    }
```

MyView_002.cshtml:

```
@model long

<h1>MyView_002</h1>

@Model
```

Configure session in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSession();
        ...
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseSession();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: @StevenSann if you use RedirectToAction like above, then you need to use `TempData` instead of `ViewData`. Since ViewData's life only lasts during current http request. ViewData values will be cleared if redirection occurs. While TempData can be used in the subsequent request. See my update

Comment: since `RedirectToAction` make new request , I can get `TempData["DataValue"]` just for one time only.  This value will gone if I refresh on `MyView_002` , right ? can I keep this value for `MyView_002` ?

Comment: @StevenSann You can use session